# terraform: syntax for source_security_group_id

Tags: terraform

I need to use the terraform **source_security_group_id** indicator to set another security group as a source for the current one. But when I try variations on obvious syntax, like

```
resource "aws_security_group" "foo-sg" {

    "ingress" = {
    "from_port" = 443
    "to_port" = 443
    "protocol" = -1
    "source_security_group_id" = "sg-9115bae1"
  }
}
```

... I get an error:

> aws_security_group.foo-sg: ingress.0: invalid or unknown key:
>   source_security_group_id

---

Anyone have an example of using this construct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The attribute name for this feature is `security_groups`, and can be used as follows:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "foo-sg" {
  ingress {
    from_port = 443
    to_port   = 443
    protocol  = "tcp"

    security_groups = ["sg-9115bae1"]
  }
}
```

Note too that the special `-1` value for `protocol`, meaning "any protocol", causes the port numbers to be ignored since only UDP and TCP have the concept of port numbers. Setting the `protocol` to `tcp`, as shown in the above example, is necessary to allow incoming connections for HTTPS.

Comment: @Mark McWiggins, you need to go through the resource's document (https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/security_group.html), that will be helpful if you have similar issue in the future.

Comment: How can I make an income rule if the sg is not yet created?

Answer (score 0):

If above code is not working , please fallow variable method. means define variable and get from outputs

```
resource "aws_security_group" "foo-sg" {
  ingress {
    from_port = 443
    to_port   = 443
    protocol  = "tcp"

    security_groups = ["${var.ec2_sg}"]
  }
}
##in variable file add this
variable = "ec2_sg" {}

then in main file give the input from another module
```